# Why JWT redirect to login page. Laravel REST Api

Tags: laravel, rest, api, jwt

I'm deploying a RestApi with Laravel 5.5 and using JWT ("tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-develop") for authentication, PostMan for test and and Php 7.3.3-1. I followed all steps from the oficial website ([JWT Tymon](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)).
It works fine when I try to login, even it return the error when password or email is wrong. But when I try to access to the content which I want to share on Api, It returns Session store not set on request.

This is my routes providers:

```
protected function mapResourcesv2()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/resources.php'));
//        Route::group([
//            'prefix' => 'api',
//            'middleware' => 'auth:api',
//            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
//        ], function ($router) {
//            require base_path('routes/resources.php');
//        });
    }
```

The line comments is the routes which Im using in all my files (a lot of routes isn't good idea having all routes in one file) Only the no-comm line works fine.

AuthController file is the same of the official website ([Quick-start](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/)).

And this is my LoginController:

```
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);
        $this->request = $request;
    }
```

```
Route::group(
    [
        'middleware' => 'api',
        'prefix' => 'auth'
    ],
    function($router)
    {
        Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
        Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
        Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');
        Route::group(
            [
                'prefix' =>  'product',
            ],
            function()
            {
                Route::post('price/{id}', 'Resources\Entrypoint\Http\Laravel\Product\ProductGetController@getPrice');
                Route::post('price', 'ProductPostController@changePrice');
            }
        );
    }
);
```

This is the routes which returns the login page (both weren't edited, maybe should I edit something?)

```
Route::get('blackboard/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showBlackboardLogin');
Route::post('blackboard/login', 'Auth\LoginController@postAdminLogin');
```

LoginController file:

```
    public function showBlackboardLogin(){

        return view('blackboard/login');
    }
```

```
    public function postAdminLogin(Request $request){
        $request->session()->put('login',Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
        $conditions = [
              'email' => $this->request->input('email'),
              'password' => $this->request->input('password'),
              'active' => 1,
        ];
        if(Auth::attempt($conditions, $this->request->has('remember'))){
            return redirect('blackboard');
        }else{
            //TODO, mensaje mal
            return redirect('blackboard/login');
        }
    }
```

In postman I'm using "Authorization" tab and "type:Bearer Token" and pasted the token generated after login.

The user should have access to the routes from '/product'.
But it only works for login, if I try to access '/me' it redirect to login page (only login works and returns the error if password is wrong). Actually the error is **Session store not set on request.**

Comment: you are using views? API? if your client and server are running on the same address why use API middleware? and that error is probably because of use of `middleware = 'api'`.

Comment: Yes, I have views. But not for api... Views are used for website and if someone want to access api, must to use postman or similar but before must to create a account in our website and then the user will use his account info to go to api/login (with post method) and will get his token.

Comment: Can i see your api login method?

Comment: public function login(Request $request){$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password'); if ($token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {return $this->respondWithToken($token);}
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

It's from official website, https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/quick-start/
I can login with api (and from website as usually I do), I want to access to api with token but it access even without token; users only have to know the URI and will get the api and I don't want it

Comment: so you want to restrict the api access to users who have secret_key(token), right?

Comment: The topic stateful vs stateless is worth to read.

Comment: Yes, thats the main idea. And of course for now if user know the URI must to use method POST not GET to get the data (which I want to restrict with TOKEN generated by JWT)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel throw status code only over AJAX requests, so, if you are using rest clients as postman you need to pass X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest or Accept: application/json over headers.